# X11VNC reacts very slow with no monitor attached

Tags: vnc

I set up a debian 10 MATE on a fanless miniPC, Quadcore Celeron, 8GB DDR3 RAM, 240GB SSD.

I would like to use this miniPC connected to LAN, with no monitor connected, only with VNC.

I tested some VNC servers and because of troubles with some, I use X11VNC.
X11VNC works great and nice and reacts nicely - until I disconnect the monitor and reboot. After reboot X11VNC reacts very slowly. Every input takes a second or two to make the miniPC react, it works fine if I attach a monitor.

fb read rate is 374 MB/sec, should be good enough.

My systemd start:

```
[Unit]
Description=VNC Server
After=multi-user.target network.target
[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /root/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How can I make X11VNC react quickly without having a monitor attached?